# Saving as a png image in android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, android-emulator, save

I am developing paint app and i save my drawing as png image. For drawing i used canvas that created with a bitmap. it works but image was corrupted. Can any one help me. I didn't check it with a real phone but on the emulator. Is that problem with emulator. I think it has very small processing ability. Am i right? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The emulator works fine. What piece of code did you use to store the bitmap as png?

The following works fine in the emulator:

```
Bitmap bitmap = createYourBitmap();
OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/test.png");
/* Write bitmap to file using JPEG or PNG and 80% quality hint for JPEG. */
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 80, stream);
stream.close();
```

Comment: I have the same thing but bitmap.compress(...) returns false, and an invalid file is created. Please help.