# Picture Quality and encryption

Tags: android, image, aes

I am using **AES** algorithm to `encrypt` image and is displaying after `decryption`.But after decryption the picture quality is significantly reducing,

now i want to know did encryption reduce picture quality?
Is there any way to enhance them

Comment: Do you convert the image into JPEG before encrypting or after encryption?

Comment: yes the image is storing in .jpg extension after encryption

Comment: Well, that's probably your problem. JPEG is a lossy format. Try using PNG.

Comment: Encryption (and decryption) is lossless. (Otherwise it would be a problem when you send your bank account details over an encrypted connection!)

Comment: Also we'll need to see some code.

Comment: @Reno why? The problem is solved already: do not use JPEG if you do not allow a quality degrade

Comment: Yes the problem is solved theoretically, even with JPG's OP can change the Q factor which may or may not be more convenient to OP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579647/how-to-save-a-jpeg-image-on-android-with-a-custom-quality-level

Comment: using which format i can achieve maximum quality

Comment: PNG is lossless and has the best quality. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573676/saving-as-a-png-image-in-android

Comment: @RaghavSood Please post your comment as an answer so this can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the JPEG format when you decrypt your image.

JPEG is a lossy format as it uses compression on your photo to save disk space. This can result in a noticeable loss of quality. Instead of JPEG, try using PNG, a lossless format for saving your file.